# HandsOnTable manualRowMove not updating the DOM

Tags: handsontable

The manualRowMove works fine visually but the underlying dom is not getting updated. After manualRowMove the HOT.getData() is showing the old sequence of data and not the latest sequence after row swap.

Please advise what I am doing wrong or is it a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on manualRowMove and moving rows around does not affect the original data source. HOT.getData() returns the original data source, which is not what the current state of the table is.

Plugins like manualRowMove, manualColMove, columnSorting are just abstractions that sit on top of the data layer. They maintain state on the handsontable object (ie the sortIndex attribute) which basically act as lookup tables from what the authors call "logical index" to "physical index". Read more about it here: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Understanding-column-sorting-plugin

It seems like you are trying to allow users to sort the order of the table then save that order. You'll have to roll your own func to walk the table and use a method like getDataAtRow() to get data in table order.

Comment: Thanks. But have you experienced that if any row gets added/removed (contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row']) from the HOT then the manualRowMove option doesn't work any more for the entire HOT or behaves abnormally.

Please check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bcm3uk62/

Please advise.

Comment: Yes, and after looking through the source, I noticed that someone forgot to add necessary code to update the manualRowPositions array after a row create or row remove. The HandsontableManualColumnsMove plugin implements the necessary functions but not the HandsontableManualRowMove plugin. I have patched my local file and may get around to submitting a pull-request on github.

Comment: So as of now there is not solution for this issue until the HOT team releases a new version with this fix. Please advice if there is any workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

the way I fixed this was to use a PHP script to push the new order to the database on the server (there needs to be some < / > swap logic, it isn't that easy in PHP land, but it is doable), in theory you could recollect the grid and "refresh" it but I didn't feel it was necessary. Obviously the original json from my database is listed by the order

```
        afterRowMove: function (oldIndex, newIndex){ 
          $.post('../ajax/partsOrder.php?id=212&new_parts_order=' + newIndex + '&old_parts_order=' + oldIndex, function(data) {                    
             var msg = ''; 
             if (data.err!=0 || data.url==0) { 
                 msg = 'Error: ' + data.err; 
             } 
             else { 
                 msg = 'Success: ' + data.msg; 
             } 
             console.log('partsOrder.php says: '+msg); 
          },"json"); 
        }
```

PS: I think this is a *major* omission from handontable, I was not impressed that the getData() doesn't simply represent the gui. In fact it's borderline criminal that they even worked on the gui at all without this